# Can complete pure souls exist in Kali Yuga?

Tags: atma, yuga, kali-yuga

According to the scriptures, is there any mention of whether complete pure souls can exist in Kali Yuga?

Comment: Define  a "pure" soul.

Comment: @Wikash_hindu as those in Satyuga

Comment: Why would this get downvoted. Considering how horrible KaliYug can be, seems like a fair question

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course.

There are many sloksa in different Puranas mentioning that Chanting of the Name of God removes all sins and makes a man pure. I am quoting one from the Garuda-Purana

> **Kalau sankirtanaad eva sarvam paapam vyaapohati**, meaning that Nama-Sankitrtana alone removes all sins in the age of kali (Reference: Omkarnath Rachanavali, Mahamilan Math,vol 1, page 318).

So many saints like Sri Chaitanya and His disciples, Nanak, Kavir,Tulsidas, Dadu, Meerabai etc took birth in the kali-yuga! **I feel their characters are as glorious as the great characters of our scriptures or of people in the Satya Yuga, if ofttimes not more,** (excluding incarnations like Sri Rama and Sri Krishna of course.)

Answer (score 1):

Atma (closest in English - soul) is pure by very definition. Can I ask if "distilled water" is pure? It is pure by very definition.

> अव्यक्तोऽयम्‌ अचिन्त्योऽयम्‌ अविकार्योऽयम्‌ उत्व्यते। तस्मादेवं
>   विदित्वैनं नानुशोचितुमर्हसि॥ Bhagavad Gita

It is "avikari". It doesn't have any impurity.

Comment: the translation of soul in 'pure soul' is not Atmaa.

Comment: Do you mean there is more than one soul!!??? Also, one of the tags of the question is 'Atma'.

Comment: yes. there are many souls.jivatma and paramatma are same only from the paramarthika point even for Advaita view

Comment: you cannot be wrong anymore, na jayate mriyate va - Gita, talks in singular NOT in plural. The purity here applies to one of three sharira (bodies). Sthul, shukshma, karan, Atma is always pure.

Comment: please read shankar's commentary carefully.No need of arguing:)

Comment: Not the only commentary, still I did. Supports my point though. http://www.swamij.com/shankara-atma-shatakam.htm